# Solve for one unknown mass in a simple pulley system

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

My class was given a problem where we would use a pulley system to calculate the mass of a pair of car keys. We attached 200g weights to each side of a pulley system and attached the keys to one of the weights. We would release the weight from a known height and measure the time for it to reach the ground to calculate acceleration. We also weighed the keys on a scale, so I know they actually weigh 37g

Using the acceleration, we are instructed to find the mass of the unknown weight. We are supposed to assume the pulley is massless and frictionless. These are my known variables:

$a=0.34m/s^2$

$m_1=0.2kg$

$m_2>m_1$

I made my free body diagrams, wrote my net force equations, and solved for T so I can use Newton's Second Law later on.

First:

$F_{net_{y1}}=T-F_{g_1}=m_1a$

$F_{net_{y1}}=T-m_1g=m_1a$

$T=m_1a+m_1g$

Second:

$F_{net_{y2}}=F_{g_2}-T=m_2a$

$T-m_2g=-m_2a$

Substitution:

$(m_1a + m_1g)-m_2g=-m_2a$

$m_1a+m_1g=m_2(-a + g)$

$$m_2=\frac{(m_1a + m_1g)}{(g - a)}$$

Plugging in values:

$$m_2=\frac{((0.2kg\times0.34m/s^2)+(0.2kg\times9.8m/s^2))}{(9.8m/s^2-0.34m/s^2)}$$

$m_2=0.214 kg$

Subtracting the 200g weight from that side, the calculated mass of the keys is 14g, when it is actually 37g. That is a 158% error...which is pretty bad. Is there a mistake in my equations, or did we collect some data that was just bad?

Comment: I've done a lot more work, and I think my work is right here. Could the weight difference be insignificant enough that the energy loss due to the weight and the friction of the pulley is relatively large?

Comment: How did you measure the acceleration? You can do a reverse calculation to find $a$. I doubt that the acceleration might be wrongly measured.

Comment: your equations are good , either $a$ is measured incorrectly or the pulleys/ropes have significant mass/friction.

Comment: The acceleration could very well be inaccurate as well. We released the heavier side from .6 meters multiple times, and consistently got 1.89 seconds for the drop time. We then used $a = \frac{2dx}{t^2}$ to find acceleration.

Comment: Thank you for verifying my equations. I will talk to my teacher tomorrow. I think my group may have used a set of keys that was too light to offset the energy loss due to the mass and friction of the rope and pulleys.

Comment: so how did you get the acceleration to be $0.34m/s^2$ its coming different very far away .

Comment: I'm confused. $a=\frac{2*.6m}{1.89s^2}=.3359m/s^2$

Comment: was the experiment done in vacuum or just open space, the drag on the weights/keys can also play a role .

Comment: Oh its 0.6m, I thought its 6m

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear and written 0.6m. And Gowtham, this is a high school AP Physics class and my school definitely doesn't have enough money for us to do it any way other than open space.

Comment: There are many things that are going to affect measurement like the mass of the string which adds to the heavier side, extension of the string, Tension is not uniform, friction, air drag etc. I guess if the experiment is done with heavier masses, small pulley and lighter and less extensible strings it would give better results.

Comment: I was going to answer my question, but apparently this is off topic, despite the fact that I was asking about a specific concept(verifying my understanding of Newton's Second Law), and demonstrated the effort to solve the problem already. Anyways, we did the data collection again, but used a set of keys that weighed $118g$. Our trials each released the keys from $0.52m$, and the fall time averaged $0.70s$. This resulted in an acceleration of $2.12m/s^2$. Plugging this back into the equation gave me a mass of $0.310kg$, meaning that the keys weighed $110g$, so my % error is $6.8$. Thanks all!

Comment: Seth, what you're asking is "Is there a mistake in my equations, or did we collect some data that was just bad?" Questions asking us to check your work are not about a specific physics concept and are thus off topic here, as described in the homework policy. Similar reasoning applies to your other question.

Comment: Okay that makes sense. Thank you for the feedback.